# How to place a figure in mid paragraph

Tags: floats

Typically a figure is placed at the end or beginning of  a section. How can I place a figure after I refer to it in a paragraph and after the current line?

Comment: Did you give a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/82917)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[ht]` option of `figure` should be sufficient for this.  And, of course, avoid paragraph breaks (blank lines) before and after the `figure` environment, if you want the figure to appear mid-paragraph.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
Here is before my figure.
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\framebox(100,100){Test}
\caption{blah blah}
\end{figure}
Here is after my figure.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]